# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Apply configuration file on nginx server

Tags: php, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to migrated my application in ebs because it was deprecated, my previous platform was:

PHP 5.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux / 2.9.8

now i'm migrating to:

PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2 / 3.0.3

This platform uses the Nginx server instead of Apache.

I was able to deploy my application but the problem is that my .htaccess configuration file was deprecated as was my .ebextensions configuration file. so I have lost the settings I had for example to get clean urls and redirects from http to https.

I have tried to transform the apache configurations to Nginx by putting the respective configuration file but apparently they have no effect.

I have tried many test configurations and I have come to the conclusion that the platform is not reading the configurations that I put.

I have tried to try for example with this little configuration, which should allow me to list the "views" directory:

cleanurl.config

```
server {
location / views / {
    autoindex on;
}
}
```

I have tried putting it in the following folders.

".ebextensions / cleanurl.config"

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/cleanurl.conf":
        mode: "000644"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
              server {
                location / views / {
                autoindex on;
                }
             }
```

".platform / nginx / conf.d / cleanurl.config"

```
server {
location / views / {
    autoindex on;
}
}
```

But I don't get results. I always get 403 Forbidden when I point to a folder. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying and trying I was able to solve it in the following way:

- I put the file in this location

```
.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/cleanurl.conf
```

- change my config file like this

```
location/views/ {
   autoindex on;
}
```

and now everything works.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried many test configurations and I have come to the conclusion that the platform is not reading the configurations that I put.

In the first case this is because the configuration files that you use are for **Amazon Linux 1** (AL1). However, you environment is PHP 7.4 running on 64bit **Amazon Linux 2** (AL2).

In your second attempt, you are using  [the config files](http://%60cleanurl.config%60) in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/` as you should. However, you are using `*.config` extension. This **wrong extension** and it [should be](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html):

```
cleanurl.conf
```

You still may have other issues, but the wrong extension could explain why the files are being **ignored**.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, I have made the changes that you suggested, but continue to ignore the configuration file, I recognize that I do not know anything about ngnix, but in the investigations I did, I know that this simple configuration in the file "cleanurl.conf" It should work, I have the "views" folder at the root of my application. maybe you could give me some simple settings that could check that the file is not being ignored?